# UFW seems to be ignoring allowed ports in specific cases

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, firewall, ufw, port

I've got a Raspberry Pi set up with UFW firewall to try and secure it as best as possible. Most of the rules seem to work absolutely fine, but for some reason, it's blocking specific connections which I've added rules to allow.

In one of the screenshots attached, there's a connection from 192.168.0.160 to the RPi on port TCP 8581. But in the other screenshot showing the active rules, I've got a Homebridge application profile which specifically allows 8581 on TCP as one of the allowed ports, and that's set up to accept from any connection within the network.

The rules shown are all of the rules I've got set up, so I don't imagine there's any conflict going on there. I've also tried both reloading the firewall and rebooting entirely, which haven't helped. If anybody has any tips to sort this out it'd be appreciated, thanks!

[image: UFW log showing blocked access]

[image: UFW active rules]

Comment: ufw ia not blocking traffic by itself, as it's a frontend for iptables. There may be another rule you can't see from its list. Use iptables to see the whole picture.

Comment: @Zip Thanks for the idea, I've had a look at iptables as suggested though and can't see anything in there which looks like it would be conflicting.

Comment: Can you post Output of `iptables -L -n`?

Comment: @stoney Hey there, thanks but I managed to get it sorted out, it seems to have been a dodgy connection causing UFW to log blocked connections, when they were actually just dropped connections.

Answer (score 0):

From an edit to the question by the original user (putting it here to separate it from the question, and as a community wiki answer):

It seems to have been the [same issue this user was having](https://serverfault.com/a/957824), where connection issues caused UFW to log the connections as blocked, when in reality the connections were just dropped with no firewall intervention.

In my case, this was caused by a faulty Apple HomePod which was having constant connection issues. Replacing that with a known-working one solved the issue entirely. Obviously that's a specific fix in my case but it for anybody else having the same issue, make sure it's not just a connection issue with the device itself.